# Installing a custom dependency with rosdep

Tags: rosdep, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Ros package (let's call it `myRosPkg`) which depends on a custom version of a python module (that we call `myCustomPkg`).
This python module is on a forked github repository.

I would like rosdep to automatically install this dependency.

To do so, here is what I have done (following the instructions given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/rosdep.yaml) and [here](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html).

#### 1.  Created a `custom_deps.yaml` with the following content:

```
myCustomPkg:
    ubuntu: |
        pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@master
```

#### 2. Append this file to `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`

```
echo file://$(readlink -f custom_deps.yaml) >> /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
```

#### 3. Update rosdep and check install (this is where it fails)

```
> rosdep update
...
> rosdep resolve myCustomPkg --os=ubuntu:xenial
rosdep detected OS: [elementary] aliasing it to: [ubuntu]
#apt
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@master

> rosdep check myRosPkg --os=ubuntu:xenial -i
rosdep detected OS: [elementary] aliasing it to: [ubuntu]
System dependencies have not been satisified:
apt pip
apt install
apt git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@master
```

Is there something wrong I did ? (maybe rosdep is not parsing the command as a multiline string?)

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295471/installing-a-custom-dependency-with-rosdep/) by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-27**:
Did you copy-paste the yaml content correctly? The following seems to be missing one level of indentation:

> ```
> myCustomPkg:
> ```

```
ubuntu: |
    ...
```

**Comment by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) on 2018-06-27**:
Yes i just forgot to put it correcly on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bash syntax you linked to is no longer supported as of rosdep 0.12 several years ago. See the top level header.

http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/rosdep.yaml

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-27**:
Duplicate: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/614

**Comment by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) on 2018-06-27**:
Thank you, and sorry again for the double post. Is there no other way of doing so?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-27**:
Since you're using pip I'd suggest using the pip installer. The best approach for this would be to use the full url in a pip rule. I don't think that's currently fully supported but a patch to extend the pip installer to support that would be appreciated.

**Comment by [ejalaa12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33860/ejalaa12/) on 2018-06-28**:
See my answer for using a pip rule. What do you mean by not *fully supported* ?